# Parse XML into DOM tree with custom object implementations in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I want to parse an XML document into a DOM tree in Java such that certain objects (e.g. instances of `org.w3c.dom.Node` or `org.w3c.dom.Element`) in the tree can be downcast to instances of classes that I have created, while minimizing the amount of XML-related code that I need to (re)implement. As a (very simple) example, if I have an XML element like:

```
<Vector size="5">
  1.0 -1.0 3.0 -2.73e2
</Vector>
```

I would like to customize the parser to instantiate the following for it:

```
public class Vector extends /* some parser class */ {
  private double[] elements;

  /* constructors; etc.*/

  public double dotProduct(Vector v) {
    /* implementation */
  }
}
```

such that I can pass instances of `Vector` created by the parser to, for example, `javax.xml.xpath` objects' methods and have them work correctly. What is the quickest way to achieve this? Is it possible with Java SE alone, or are third-party libraries (e.g. Xerces) necessary?

Comment: Are you in control of how the XML looks like?

Comment: Yes, I am in complete control of the XML and its schema(s).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your requirements are, but assuming you're in control of what the XML looks like, what I would use is [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).  It will allow you to skip all the DOM manipulation completely.

Now from [their 2 minute tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html), it may not seem like it's built for this use case, but it actually is.  You create your java classes first, make sure they generate the XML the way you want it to look, and then use it to read your already existing XML back into your program as XStream objects.  It's a very pleasant library to use.

Comment: I need the changes made to my objects (i.e. their members) to be reflected in the DOM immediately. It seems that XStream instantiates a separate set of objects from the DOM.

Comment: Why do you need a DOM at all?

Comment: Primarily to use XPath to navigate the XML hierarchy.

Comment: @TechnocratiK But you can read the whole file into an object tree and traverse the data in the objects, avoiding XPath.  If you prefer to use XPath then XStream isn't for you.  But if you want to extract XML to objects, XStream is the best tool.  I don't know of anything that does it half way.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The `Binder` mechanism in JAXB may be what you are looking for.  It doesn't allow a DOM node to be cast to a domain object, but it does maintain a link between a domain object and its corresponding DOM node.

**Note:**  The following code ran clean when using the MOXy as the JAXB provider, but threw an exception when using the impl of JAXB included in the version of the JDK I happen to be running.

**JAVA MODEL**

I will use the following domain model for this example.

**Customer**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="phoneNumber")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class PhoneNumber {

    private String type;
    private String number;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html)

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**XML (input.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
    <phoneNumbers>
        <phoneNumber type="work">555-1111</phoneNumber>
        <phoneNumber type="home">555-2222</phoneNumber>
    </phoneNumbers>
</customer>
```

**DEMO CODE**

In the demo code below I will do the following:

1. Use XPath to find a child element, then use the `Binder` to find the corresponding domain object.
2. Update the domain object and use the `Binder` to apply the change to the DOM.
3. Update the DOM and use the `Binder` to apply the change to the domain object.

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.Binder;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse("src/forum16599580/input.xml");

        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
        binder.unmarshal(document);

        // Use Node to Get Object
        Node phoneNumberElement = (Node) xpath.evaluate("/customer/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[2]", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = (PhoneNumber) binder.getJAXBNode(phoneNumberElement);

        // Modify Object to Update DOM
        phoneNumber.setNumber("555-2OBJ");
        binder.updateXML(phoneNumber);
        System.out.println(xpath.evaluate("/customer/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[2]", document, XPathConstants.STRING));

        // Modify DOM to Update Object
        phoneNumberElement.setTextContent("555-2DOM");
        binder.updateJAXB(phoneNumberElement);
        System.out.println(phoneNumber.getNumber());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
555-2OBJ
555-2DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been through exactly this over the last 10 years, building XML DOMs for chemistry, graphics, maths, etc. My own solution has been to use a DOM where the elements can be subclassed (I use xom.nu but there are others). The w3c dom does not allow subclassing (IIRC) and so you would have to build a delegate model. (I tried this many years ago and rejected it, but software tools and libraries make all this much easier (e.g. the IDE will generate delegat methods).

If you are doing a lot, and especially if you are creating a lot of custom methods then I would recommend rolling your own system. The effort will be in your methods (dotProduct), not the XML.

Here, for example, [is my class for a 3D point](https://bitbucket.org/wwmm/cmlxom/src/9b10e8a21171b1c4874ee4a65db8ae29edd88b1d/src/main/java/org/xmlcml/cml/element/CMLPoint3.java?at=default).

```
public class CMLPoint3 extends AbstractPoint3
```

(which extends the base class CMLElement, which extends nu.xom.Element

The creation of elements is a factory. Here's a chunk of my SVGDOM:

```
public static SVGElement readAndCreateSVG(Element element) {
    SVGElement newElement = null;
    String tag = element.getLocalName();
    if (tag == null || tag.equals(S_EMPTY)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no tag");
    } else if (tag.equals(SVGCircle.TAG)) {
        newElement = new SVGCircle();
    } else if (tag.equals(SVGClipPath.TAG)) {
        newElement = new SVGClipPath();
    } else if (tag.equals(SVGDefs.TAG)) {
        newElement = new SVGDefs();
    } else if (tag.equals(SVGDesc.TAG)) {
        newElement = new SVGDesc();
    } else if (tag.equals(SVGEllipse.TAG)) {
        newElement = new SVGEllipse();
    } else if (tag.equals(SVGG.TAG)) {

...
    } else {
            newElement = new SVGG();
            newElement.setClassName(tag);
            System.err.println("unsupported svg element: "+tag);
        }
        if (newElement != null) {
            newElement.copyAttributesFrom(element);
            createSubclassedChildren(element, newElement);
        }
        return newElement;
```

You can see tools for copying and recursing.

The questions you need to think about are:

- how closely is this bound to an XSD
- do I use XSD data Types
- do I validate on input
- am I using the DOM as the primary data structure (I do)
- how frequently will things change.

FWIW I have been through 6 revisions of this and am contemplating another (using Scala as the main engine).